# How to make only those props pass to a component where component is decided on the basis of switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this component which can be any of the `NumberRating`, `StarRating`,`PollRating` Component as the component is decided on the basis of a `switch` statement in my code .

One of the component, `NumberRating`, has only maximum as props that it can receive, while `StarRating` can receive maximum as well as minimum and `Poll` can receive none of the two.

How do I go about passing props to my Component in this case?

```
renderBlock = () => {
  let Component;
  let ratingType = this.props.item && this.props.item.ratingType;
  if (ratingType !== null) {
    switch (ratingType) {
      case "1":
      default:
        Component = NumberRating;
        break;

      case "2":
        Component = NumberRating;
        break;
      case "3":
        Component = StarRating;
        break;
      case "4":
        Component = PollRating;
        break;
    }
  }

  // to this component I need to pass props .Also sometimes in my item i may have maximum and at times ,I may not minimum associated with item.
  return <Component />;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage the `switch` logic to both determine the props and the type of the component to render:

```
renderBlock = () => {
  let Component;
  let ratingType = this.props.item && this.props.item.ratingType;
  if (ratingType !== null) {
    switch (ratingType) {
      default:
      case "1":
      case "2":
        return <NumberRating maximum={this.props.maximum} />;
      case "3":
        return (
          <StarRating
            maximum={this.props.maximum}
            minimum={this.props.minimum}
          />
        );
      case "4":
        return <PollRating />;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: But sometimes ,I may not have maximum or minimum in item.How do i make sure ,I don't end up accessing something which is no there ?

Answer (score 1):

```
renderBlock = () => {
  let Component;
  let ratingType = this.props.item && this.props.item.ratingType;
  const props = {};
  if (ratingType !== null) {
    switch (ratingType) {
      case "1":
        Component = NumberRating;
        props.maximum = this.props.maximum;
        break;
      case "2":
        Component = NumberRating;
        break;
      case "3":
        Component = StarRating;
        props.maximum = this.props.maximum;
        props.minimum = this.props.minimum;
        break;
      case "4":
        Component = PollRating;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  return(
    <Component {...props}/>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah ,it helped me .

Answer (score 0):

I took help from one of the answer and here is what worked for me .

```
renderBlock=()=>{
        let Component;
        let ratingType=this.props.item && this.props.item.ratingType;
        const props={};
        if(ratingType!==null){
            switch(ratingType){

                case '1':default:
                    Component=NumberRating
                    if(this.props.item.maximum)
                        props.maxRating=this.props.item && this.props.item.maximum
                    break;

                case '2':
                    Component=NumberRating;
                    if(this.props.item.maxRating)
                        props.maxRating=this.props.item && this.props.item.maximum
                    break;
                case '3':
                    Component=StarRating;
                    if(this.props.item.maximum)
                        props.maxRating=this.props.item && this.props.item.maximum
                    if(this.props.item.minimum)
                        props.value=this.props.item && this.props.item.minimum
                    break;
                case '4':
                    Component=PollRating;
                    break;

            }
        }


        return(
            <Component {...props}
            />
        );
    }
```